# How I can make new pop up windows to appear in the same desktop of their app?

Tags: x11, xfce, workspaces

I'm using XFCE and I have the following situation:

I open app on desktop #1 --> switch to desktop #2 --> app on desktop 1 opens a pop-up window on desktop #2.

How do I change it? How do I make XFCE open new pop-up windows in the same desktop in which their main application is open?