# in KDE, can I create a rule that makes a new window appear in the desktop of the app that created it?

Tags: window-manager, desktop, kde4, matlab

This has been asked before: [How I can make new pop up windows to appear in the same desktop of their app?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/203906/324792), but it was for a different WM, and there are no answers. Maybe there is an answer for KDE?

I am using virtual desktops to organize things. I want different desktops to be different environments that don't interfere with each other.

However, when an application, in a desktop I'm not currently in, opens a new window, it will be created in my current desktop. This is usually annoying (unless I'm not doing any interactive work), and it always breaks the order I'm trying to keep.

I have tried the "Special window settings" option, but it seems that there are only two general options -

1. Force a window (configurable class etc.) to always appear on a *specific* desktop (which is not what I want) - there are details of when and how but no way to say "the window of the creating app"
2. Not forcing at all - in which case, new windows will appear on the *current* desktop, which is what I have now.

What I want, and can't find, is simply a way to make new windows appear in the same desktop as the application (window? process?) that created them.

I'm using KDE 4.3.5, and I only have user privileges. The application in question is usually (but not always) Matlab.

Comment: In kde plasma 5 when an app (present on an other virtual desktop) create a window that trigger the focus it get created on its desktop, if you are using a single monitor then not only it get created on its desktop but the active virtual desktop is switched as well... any other needed customisation can be done with a custom kwin script... any way this answer/comment is for KDE5 i don't know what's possible for v4...